# Don't show a notification from firebase in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the code in firebase functions:

```
exports.androidPushNotification = functions.database
.ref("/chat/{pushId}")
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notification", {
        data: {
            senderId: snapshot.val().senderId,
        },

        notification: {
            title: `${snapshot.val().name} has sent a message.`,
            body: snapshot.val().message,
        },
    });
});
```

This is onMessageReceived in android studio:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

    if(remoteMessage.notification == null){
        return
    }

    val mAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    if(mAuth.currentUser?.uid == null){
        return
    }

    if(remoteMessage.data["senderId"] == mAuth.currentUser?.uid){
        return
    }

    generateNotification(remoteMessage.notification?.title!!, remoteMessage.notification?.body!!)
}
```

I have everyone subscribed to a topic called "notification".

This is for a chat app where everyone is in one big chat. I don't want the person who sent the message to receive the notification.

The code is working where it returns if the user sent it but the sender still receives the notification.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, so the problem is probably elsewhere. I recommend putting a breakpoint on `if(remoteMessage.data["senderId"] == mAuth.currentUser?.uid){` and running the code in a debugger. When it hits the breakpoint, check all variables in that line to see which of them isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: When I removed the generateNotification function I still receive the notification. The code is working but still shows notification from firebase.

Comment: Did you set the breakpoint, run in a debugger, and check the variables as I said in my previous comment?

Comment: Debugger: remoteMessage = data = value[0] = "the_id_is_correct"

Comment: How do you send a notification to everyone except the user who sent it.

Comment: I still receive notifications without onMessageReceived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending to a topic, there is no way to exclude one subscriber from receiving the message.

What you *can* do however is send a **data only** message and handle that in code. If you include a `notification` node however (as you do), the system will display that notification if the app is not actively being used. So the filtering you do only works if you only have a `data` node in the message, and no `notification` node.

Comment: Just sending data in the notification worked! Thank you for your help. 